# Should the sandbox be moved to the main site?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1067/9498 and the discussion here: [How can new users use the Sandbox?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-can-new-users-use-the-sandbox/1067#comment3632_1013)

In my question [How can new users use the Sandbox?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1013/9498) , I question whether the sandbox should be moved to the main site. Jan Dvorak convinced me that it might be a good idea. Please vote here (on the accepted answer) on whether it should or should not be moved to the main site. Also, feel free to post any concerns, etc that should be addressed concerning this.

The answer is only accepted to make it easier to find.

Post any suggestions for what this sandbox should be like as an answer and people can vote on these too.

Comment: Should we also use this for suggestions on what the new sandbox should be like? Like post answers and have people vote?

Comment: OK, the other sandbox is really getting too long. We need to decide where to post it quickly now.  I vote to move it to the main site (although meta's function is really more along its line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the sandbox should be moved to the main site. Please vote up or down on this answer regarding this decision, maybe commenting your concerns. This answer should have an overwhelming majority for migration to the main site before we decide to do so.

Comment: Also, it should be _one_ sandbox. No need to reimplement paging. Reminding users of the answer sorting is useful.

Comment: Migrate the actual sandbox or create the mark 9 sandbox there?

Comment: @Victor I think create the mark 9 there.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but we would need to put a note in current sandbox to inform all visitors that the sandbox was moved.

Comment: @user2509848 Just like in the old sandboxes, link to the new one. At least, that is what I think.

Comment: @Quincunx Yes, that is basically what I meant.

Comment: "no-one should be getting rep from it" -- are you sure about that? It will motivate people to use the sandbox

Comment: @JanDvorak I think that is too much motivation. Consider my comment on this question; maybe that should be posted as a suggestion.

Comment: Rep or no rep, it seems to be in need of a more conspicuous location. I do agree with Jan that if it goes main-site it should be a single sandbox.

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be community-wiki because no-one should be getting rep from it. However, this does not mean that anyone can edit each other's post without asking.

Counterargument: rep will motivate people to use the sandbox.

Comment: I was on Community's page the other day, and one of its functions is to own questions and answers that people should not gain rep from: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: I further suggest that this should be done each 1st day of the month. So we can get one sandbox for each month. If they get clogged quickly, we can create one for days 1-15 and another for days 16 onwards.

Answer (score 3):

If moving to the main site, and only allowing one sandbox, then my concern is that there will be simply too many answers there. And even after filtering by activity it would just look like a huge mess. So my proposals:

1. Make it a community-wiki. Gaining rep is good, but the next two points will make the gained rep useless anyway
2. Delete your answer shortly after posting it to the main site. As it's already posted as a separate question there is no use for it polluting the sandbox. The answer can be flagged and deleted after one week of posting it.
3. You have one month to gather enough information to fix your problem. If you don't post it after a month it can be flagged and deleted.

By flagged and deleted I mean it's still up to the mods / high-rep users to decide whether to really delete the answer or not, but before the time limit they should never delete them (unless flagged for other reasons, like spam or abuse), and should also decline any delete request flags on these answers.

Comment: High rep users can still see deleted answers, so for them it will still be clogged up.

Comment: Given the choice between "too many answers on sandbox" and "too many bad questions on main site", I'd choose the former.