# Would you support the sandbox being Community Wiki in order to allow it to move to main?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

Personally, I am against the sandbox being CW if it's on meta, but I'm very happy for it to be CW if it's on main (since it's unlikely it will work on main otherwise, so my small objections are insignificant).

Since this may affect the [decision on whether to move the sandbox to main](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/move-the-sandbox-to-main), but opinion on the CW aspect cannot easily be measured in a general post, this is a specific post to measure just that aspect.

Comment: I think this question adds confusion rather than clarity. There are four cases (CW or not, main or meta), and the title of the question asks us to consider two (main + CW, main + not CW) whereas the two answers ask us to consider a different two (main + CW, meta + not CW). And the question doesn't give the enough context for me to understand why it's being asked, or whether I (as someone who doesn't care whether it's CW or not, but does care about main vs meta) should be voting.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I see what you mean. I've edited the question title to hopefully remove that confusion without invalidating the answers. If there's still any contradiction or ambiguity let me know (I'm trying to avoid deleting or editing the answers as they have several votes up and down already).

Comment: Part of my point was that there's no way of knowing (in particular) how many of the upvotes for "No" are votes for "Sandbox should not move to main" rather than "Sandbox should not be CW". I think it would be better to delete the question and start again with 4 answers.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess trusting that people will only vote on the issue at hand was a little naive of me. Is it generally acceptable to delete and start from scratch after a fair bit of voting has been done?

Comment: I've [posted an alternative question showing all 4 options](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/4-options-for-the-sandbox-main-or-meta-community-wiki-or-not). I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 9):

## No the sandbox should not be CW (so it cannot move to main)

The benefits of being on main are not strong enough to justify making the sandbox CW.

Comment: -1 (can't vote)

Answer (score 1):

## Yes I am happy for the sandbox to be CW on main

My objections to CW are not strong enough to lose the benefits of having the sandbox on main where everyone can post to it without a rep limit.

Comment: +1 (can't vote)