# 4 options for the sandbox: Main or Meta & Community Wiki or not

Tags: discussion, sandbox

Following Peter Taylor's comments that pointed out that [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/would-you-support-the-sandbox-being-community-wiki-in-order-to-allow-it-to-move) (now deleted) is not giving meaningful voting results with only 2 options, here are all 4 options as answers so that I'm no longer asking a leading question.

Please vote up and down on as many answers as you have an opinion on, so we can see a more reliable record of the community's opinion. However, be aware that all the answers are posted by me, so voting on all of them at once may lead to your votes being reversed, as Doorknob pointed out in chat:

> (I'm a bit afraid people are going to get whacked with the serial-voting-reversal script on that. As a workaround, I'm upvoting one answer, downvoting two, and coming back later to downvote the third.)

## Feel free to edit any of the answers to add points for or against.

Comment: Answers will be relevant to the eventual decision on [Move the sandbox to main](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/move-the-sandbox-to-main)

Answer (score 17):

## The sandbox should be on Meta but not Community Wiki

Comment: +1 The sandbox is inherently meta, and doesn't need to be on main just to circumvent the 5 rep requirement.

Answer (score -1):

## The sandbox should be on Main as Community Wiki

Answer (score -7):

## The sandbox should be on Meta as Community Wiki

Answer (score -15):

## The sandbox should be on Main but not Community Wiki

Comment: - a billion if I could (but I can't so -1)